# what is numpy way of arranging numpy 2D array based on 2D numpy array of index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2 ,3], [9,8,7]])
y = np.array([[2,1 ,0], [1,0,2]])

x[y]
```

Expected output:

```
array([[3,2,1], [8,9,7]])
```

If x and y were 1D arrays, then x[y] would work. So what is the numpy way or most pythonic or efficient way of doing this for 2D arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the corresponding row indices.

One way is:

```
>>> x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[..., None], y]
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [8, 9, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the linear indices from `y` and then use those to extract specific elements from `x`, like so -

```
# Linear indices from y, using x's shape
lin_idx = y + np.arange(y.shape[0])[:,None]*x.shape[1]

# Use np.take to extract those indexed elements from x
out = np.take(x,lin_idx)
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: x
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [9, 8, 7]])

In [48]: y
Out[48]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 2]])

In [49]: lin_idx = y + np.arange(y.shape[0])[:,None]*x.shape[1]

In [50]: lin_idx  # Compare this with y
Out[50]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 5]])

In [51]: np.take(x,lin_idx)
Out[51]: 
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [8, 9, 7]])
```